# Convert list of 14 arrays to single array (Keras Value Error)

Tags: python, numpy, keras

I get the following Keras Value error when I try to train my model.

> ValueError: Error when checking model target: the list of Numpy arrays
>   that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected.
>   Expected to see 1 array(s), but instead got the following list of 14
>   arrays:

```
   [array([['0'],
           ['0'],
           ['0'],
           ['0'],
           ['0'],
           ['0'],
           ['0'],
           ['0'],
           ['1'],
           ['0'],
           ['0'],
           ['0'],
           ['0'],
           ['0'],
       ...
```

When I try to reshape y_col using:

```
y_col = np.stack( y_col, axis=0 )
```

I get:

```
TypeError: If class_mode="multi_output", y_col must be a list. Received ndarray.
```

if I'm just trying to do it with

```
y_col = np.array(y_col)
```

I get same error.

Dataframe:

```
      Path    black  grey  green blue   etc....
0  12345.jpg    1      0       1  0
1  12345.jpg    0      0       1  0
2  12345.jpg    1      0       0  1
3  12345.jpg    0      1       0  1
4  12345.jpg    0      0       1  1
5  12345.jpg    0      0       1  1
```

The model for each image should be a single array of 14 elements [0,0,1,1,0,1,0,...], but looks like you are passing 14 different arrays for each image.

The problem occurs in the CNN network that recognizes the colors of products (clothes)
One product can have more than one color e.g. [0.0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1]

initially y_col looks:

```
['beige',
 'black',
 'blue',
 'brown',
 'gray',
 'green',
 'multicolor',
 'orange',
 'pink',
 'red',
 'violet',
 'white',
 'yellow',
 'transparent']
```

generator:

```
def get_generator(filename, number=None):
    # 
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, delimiter=' ', names=color_list, dtype="str")
    if number:
        df = df[:number]
    # 
    gen = image.ImageDataGenerator()
    # 
    directory = os.path.dirname(filename)
    # 
    return gen.flow_from_dataframe(df, directory, "path", y_col = y_col , target_size=(224, 224), batch_size=32,class_mode="multi_output")
```

Comment: upload the raw list

Comment: did you try `y_col = [y for y in y_col]` ?

Answer (score 2):

**`y_col` is a list that contains a `numpy` array.**

```
y_col = [np.array([['0'], 
                   ['0'], 
                   ['0'], 
                   ['0'], 
                   ['0'], 
                   ['0'], 
                   ['0'], 
                   ['0'], 
                   ['1']])]
```

**Use:**

```
 y_new  = y_col[0].flatten()
 y_new = [int(y) for y in y_new]
```

OR ***in one line:***

```
 y_new = [int(y) for y in y_col[0].flatten()]
```

**Output:**

```
y_new                                                                                      
#[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

Comment: y_col is initially a color list and only then are the numbers assigned in the generator. In this case, I can't make `` Flatten '' directly on y_col. I corrected the question